# Vagrant up fails on Booting VM

Tags: boot, virtualbox, vagrant

I have installed the latest release from Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed VirtualBox like that:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
```

and I downloaded the latest release from Vagrant and installed it like that:

```
sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.0.1_x86_64.deb
```

Then I installed homestead following these [instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#first-steps)

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead 
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
cd ~/Homestead
git checkout v7.0.1
bash init.sh
```

I removed the `ssh key` line from the `Homestead.yaml` file.

If I tried to start vagrant with

```
vagrant up --debug
```

then my PC freezes on the Booting VM line.

Here is a screen-shot that I took with my camera:

[image]

I have no idea why this is not working. I installed Ubuntu 2 times and repeated all these steps. Always producing the same error. What is causing this issue?

I have also asked this question [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9360#issuecomment-357532652)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: Vagrant up fails on Booting VM

Hey @Adam I am also getting this problem for last 3-4 days in one of my workstation and didn't look for any solution until today when I upgraded second workstation's kernel. I think this problem is causing of new Ubuntu kernel `4.13.0-26-generic`. I have booted to previous kernel `4.10.0-42-generic` and tried `vagrant up` and it worked perfectly for both of my workstations. It is a temporary fix not a permanent solution though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a issue reported to ubuntu [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1736116).

You can download virtualbox directly from official site. The follow comment from tobiaskarnat said that:

> I can confirm Virtualbox 5.2 from virtualbox.org also works with
>   linux-hwe 4.13.0-29.32~16.04.1 from ppa:canonical-kernel-team/pti
>   which fixes Spectre with IBRS/IBPB.
>
> And I hope Virtualbox implements IBRS/IBPB path through to also allow
>   Spectre protection in vms.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the bug report reference. I was just about to find out how to add such a bug report :P.